# getdefaultlocale returning None when running sync.db on Django project in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

OSX 10.7.3, PyCharm version 2.5 build PY 117.200

I'll run through how I get the error:

1. I start a new project
2. Create a new VirtualEnv and select Python 2.7 as my base interpreter (leave inherit global packages un-ticked)
3. Click Install and choose Django v1.4
4. Select `Django` project type
5. Tick `Enable Admin`
6. Open `settings.py` and add `sqlite3` to `DATABASES:ENGINE`
7. Run `sync.db`
8. Get to the point of creating a database superuser
9. locale error

The problem seems to be that getdefaultlocale() method is not returning anything (well, None).

```
return getpass.getuser().decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])
    TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

However if I enable the virtualenv `workon MyApplication` and run `python` with the following code:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Feb  7 2012, 23:16:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.10.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> print locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_GB', 'UTF-8')
```

**So does anybody know what's going on?**

### Full Output:

```
bash -cl "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py syncdb"
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 180, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/ash/Development/PycharmProjects/Tester/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 110, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 189, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 73, in create_superuser
    call_command("createsuperuser", interactive=True, database=db)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 150, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 70, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 105, in get_default_username
    default_username = get_system_username()
  File "/Users/ash/.virtualenvs/Tester/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 85, in get_system_username
    return getpass.getuser().decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])
TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It may be caused by GUI application (PyCharm) having different environment than your Terminal, see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1160 for details how to fix it, probably adding `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` for GUI applications will fix it.

Comment: ...but I may be wrong as it still runs via `bash -cl` and should have access to the same terminal environment.

Comment: I should also note that running `import locale; print locale.getdefaultlocale` returns `(None, None)` in the PyCharm Django console.

Comment: This is [Django Bug #16017](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16017)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically the reason this occurs is that PyCharm doesn't, by default, have access to environmental variables.

I've found 3 solutions to this problem:

1. Set a global environmental variable, using the link CrazyCoder suggests in the comments to this question.
2. Run PyCharm from a terminal window by changing to the PyCharm application directory and running `./pycharm` (possibly create a symlink in your PATH to make this less inconvenient)
3. Open PyCharm preferences, browse to `Console > Django Console`, type in your required environmental variables as you would in your bash profile e.g. `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

I'd suggest the 3rd way as most elegant, although it's annoying that variables aren't loaded by default.

Comment: You can also set a respective environment variable in the `settings.py` of your Django project like that: `import os; os.environ['LANG'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'`. I had the same problem in Eclipse and this solved it for me.

Comment: @Peter Stahl comment, works for me, I had this problem but I was not using pycharm

Answer (score 7):

Go onto Terminal:

```
$ nano .bash_profile
```

add:

```
export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

(or use the locale -a command to see which ones are available to you)

save and try again.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried after googling. PyCharm doesn't see anything in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Pycharm, I had the exact same problem with or without Pycharm, which I also prefer Pycharm as my default IDE btw

Comment: Well I can run the method that causes the error in my shell with no problems and I haven't got those environmental variables set.