# Fabric, can't get default locale on django

Tags: python, django, locale, fabric

I have the following django management command:

fabrictest.py

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
import locale

class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        print locale.getdefaultlocale()
```

Which I can run locally:

```
$ /home/user/env/bin/python manage.py fabrictest
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

However, when I run the command remotely using the following fabric task

```
@task
def test():
    # run manage.py using the python bin from the virtualenv

    with cd(env.project_root):
        run("/home/user/env/bin/python manage.py fabrictest")
```

I get the following output

```
[server] Executing task 'test'
[server] run: /home/user/env/bin/python manage.py fabrictest
[server] out: (None, None)
```

Why do I get `(None, None)` instead of `('en_US', 'UTF-8')`?. This generates errors for some other management scritps (namely, `syncdb` when creating the superuser).

Comment: use '/home/user/env/bin/python' when you run the local manage.py as it may not be the same. Also are you on the same remote server?

Comment: I actually use the virtualenv's python bin when I run `manage.py` locally from the server. I'll edit the question to make it more explicit. 

It is the exact same server on both cases, the first time I run it locally (by `ssh`ing into the server) and the second time I run it remotely (using fabric to connect to the server).

Comment: does it work as: `run("LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /home/user/env/bin/python manage.py fabrictest")`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339963/getdefaultlocale-returning-none-when-running-sync-db-on-django-project-in-pychar) it seems like those are picked up environment variables.

You could export them manually, either in the run() or with a prefix() context manager. You may also try setting pty to False in the run().

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/locale#locale.getdefaultlocale):

> According to POSIX, a program which has not called setlocale(LC_ALL,
>   "") runs using the portable 'C' locale. Calling setlocale(LC_ALL, "")
>   lets it use the default locale as defined by the LANG variable. Since
>   we don't want to interfere with the current locale setting we thus
>   emulate the behavior in the way described above...
>
> ...code and encoding can be None in case the values cannot
>           be determined.

If you program can't run using the `'C'` locale then call `setlocale()` and/or set appropriate environment variables e.g., `LANG`.