# Different datetime.strftime output with same locale settings

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I use python 2.7 and it turned out that datetime.strftime produces different output on different environments (both unix-based) with the same locale settings.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('RU', 'utf-8'))
print locale.getlocale()
print datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y %d %B, %A")
```

On first env I got:

> ('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')
>
> 2016 21 января, четверг (month name is in genitive form)

On the second:

> ('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')
>
> 2016 21 Январь, Четверг (month name is in infinitive form)

As you can see there are also some differences in upper/lowercase letters. PYTHONIOENCODING is set to utf_8 in both cases.

What is the reason of this behavior and more important is there a way to make the second env work the way the first does?

Comment: what is the output of `python --version` on both systems?

Comment: first - 2.7.10, second - 2.7.6. It seems like we have an answer, right? I synch them and than write back.

Comment: does [using `babel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34603979/4279) produce the same results on your different systems?

Comment: @wayne It appeared to be harder than I thought: virtenv based on 2.7.10 now produce difficulties with other external libs( so taking  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34927103/5213700) into consideration I just gonna give up and just code it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the output of the [C `strftime()` call](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) here; Python delegates to it. That function picks those strings from locale files stored outside the control of Python.

See the [`locale` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/locale.5.html) for a description of the file format; you are looking for the `LC_TIME` `mon` and `day` lists here.

On Mac OS X stores things slightly differently, the files are stored in `/usr/share/locale/`; for `ru_RU` time definitions there is a file called `/usr/share/locale/ru_RU.UTF-8/LC_TIME`; it puts values one per line in a certain order. The first 24 lines are months (abbreviated and full), for example; with the full month names defined as:

```
января
февраля
марта
апреля
мая
июня
июля
августа
сентября
октября
ноября
декабря
```

Because this is OS and system specific, you'd have to use a different system altogether to format your dates if you need these strings to be consistent across different platforms.

If you are trying to *parse* a date string, you won't get far with the `datetime` or `time` modules. Try the [`dateparser` project](http://dateparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead, which [understands the different Russian forms](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/blob/master/data/languages.yaml#L585-L706):

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse(u'2016 21 января, четверг')
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 21, 0, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse(u'2016 21 Январь, Четверг')
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 21, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately my aim is not to format but to parse some strings into dates. So if I get you right my only option is to code it manually or find external lib(

Comment: @superduper: I'm afraid so. Parsing dates using *local natural language* is a hard problem though.

Comment: @superduper: I've added a alternative that works with Russian dates, at least.

Comment: it works perfectly and was easy to implement. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Python's `datetime.strftime` [wraps `time.strftime`](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Modules/datetimemodule.c#L1346), and the latter [delegates to the underlying C's](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Modules/timemodule.c#L500) [`strftime(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). Apparently, that's what it returns.