# print Israel currency using locale

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, locale

I'm using `locale.currency(100)` to display currency [works fine - gives back `'$100.00'`], but I can't get it to display Israeli currency...

I tried playing with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'il_IL.UTF-8')` but that just prompted `Error: unsupported locale setting`. (same goes for trying other countries - `'ru_RU.UTF-8'`)

As *@jdehesa* commented, the right locale for Israel should be `'he_IL.UTF-8'` instead of `'il_IL.UTF-8'`. Checked that too, and got the same error.

I have no idea where to look, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34603979/3512538) didn't help.

---

My machine's Locale:

```
C:\> systeminfo | findstr "Locale"
System Locale:             he;Hebrew
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
```

*BTW, I'm using Python3 on Windows 8 (tried checking it also on [ideone](https://ideone.com/ideone/Index/submit/)) for both Python 2&3*

Comment: Interestingly, I can reproduce the error in Windows with Python 2 but not with Python 3. I don't know what may be making the difference, the point where the exception is raised look pretty similar in both versions of the C module ([2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/_localemodule.c), [3.6](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_localemodule.c)). Unrelatedly, it seems the right locale for Israel would be `he_IL`.

Comment: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'he_IL.UTF-8') works on my Mac (python 3.6.5) and locale.currency prints ש״ח correctly

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check first in your terminal which locale is installed in your system (call depends on your os):

```
$ locale -a
```

Additional you might set all settings, not only the time ;-)

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'il_IL.UTF-8')
```

In python that works on my system:

```
In [1]: import locale

In [2]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
Out[2]: 'LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8'

In [3]: locale.currency(100)
Out[3]: '100,00 €'

In [4]: locale.getlocale()
Out[4]: ('en_US', 'UTF-8')

In [5]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
Out[5]: 'en_US.UTF-8'

In [6]: locale.currency(100)
Out[6]: '$100.00'
```

Maybe check this thread too:

[Python locale error: unsupported locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting)